# Google drive folder with multiple sub folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have this script I found online [here](https://www.pbainbridge.co.uk/2021/05/bulk-create-google-drive-folders-with.html) that creates a folder on google drive from my google sheet and one sub folder. I know it should be possible to add multiple sub folders but I am completely stuck.

Sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m4DNKXF3DGL227YFlT9eCtT7g2Nz27EfKMYiSJ1Opl4/edit#gid=0

Code:

```
  
  
  // Log starting of the script
  logEvent('Script finished');
  
  
}


/*
This Function loops through each row and initiates the creation of a Google Drive Folder
along with a sub-folder.
Permissions are added if applicable.
*/

function createFolders(spreadsheetData) {

  // extract data from name:value pair array
  var ss = spreadsheetData['ss'];
  var timeZone = spreadsheetData['timeZone'];
  var dataSheet = spreadsheetData['dataSheet'];
  var destinationFolderId = spreadsheetData['destinationFolderId'];
  var permissionFlag = spreadsheetData['permissionFlag'];
  var folderLinkCol = spreadsheetData['folderLinkCol'];
  var permAddedCol = spreadsheetData['permAddedCol'];
  var data = spreadsheetData['data'];

  // get last Row number
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();


  // start of loop to go through each row in turn ********************************
  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {

    // extract values from row of data so easier to work with
    var folderNameP1 = data[i][0];
    Logger.log('folderNameP1 is: ' + folderNameP1);
    var folderNameP2 = data[i][1];
    Logger.log('folderNameP2 is: ' + folderNameP2);
    var subFolderName = data[i][2];
    Logger.log('subFolderName is: ' + subFolderName);
    var permissionEmail = data[i][3];
    Logger.log('permissionEmail is: ' + permissionEmail);
    var folderLink = data[i][4];
    Logger.log('folderLink is: ' + folderLink);


    // check Folder Link column is empty before proceeding, so no existing Folder
    if (folderLink == '') {

      // create a name for the new Parent Folder
      var folderName = folderNameP1 + ' - ' + folderNameP2;
      Logger.log('Folder name is: ' + folderName);

      // display Toast notification
      ss.toast(folderName, 'Creating Folders');

      // run Function to create Parent Folder and sub-folder
      var folderDetails = createFolder(folderName, destinationFolderId, subFolderName);

      // check new Folders created successfully
      if (folderDetails) {

        // extract Url/Ids
        var newFolderUrl = folderDetails['newFolderUrl'];
        var newFolderId = folderDetails['newFolderId'];
        var subFolderID = folderDetails['subFolderID'];

        // set Folder Link cell using new Parent Folder Url
        var newFolderLink = '=HYPERLINK("' + newFolderUrl + '","' + folderName + '")';
        dataSheet.getRange(i + 1, folderLinkCol).setFormula(newFolderLink);


        // check if Permissions need adding - set in 'Config' sheet
        if (permissionFlag == 'Yes') {

          // run Function to add Folder permissions
          var currentRow = i + 1;
          var addPermissionsFlag = addPermissions(timeZone, dataSheet, permissionEmail,
            newFolderId, subFolderID, currentRow, permAddedCol);

          // if problem adding Permissions return for status message
          if (addPermissionsFlag == false) {
            // display Toast notification and return false flag
            ss.toast('Problem adding Permissions to: ' + folderName, 'Error');
            return false;
          }
          else {
            // no problem adding permissions
          }

        }
        else {
          // do nothing as permissions not required 
        }

        // flush spreadsheet to update each row as completed
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();

      }
      else {
        // write error into 'Permission Added?' cell and return false value
        dataSheet.getRange(i + 1, folderLinkCol).setValue('Error creating folder. Please see Logs');
        // new Folder not created successfully
        return false;
      }

    }
    else {
      // Folder Link column not empty so do nothing
    }


  }// end of loop to go through each row in turn **********************************


  // completed successfully
  return true;


}


/*
Function to create new Google Drive Folder and return its Url/Id.
*/

function createFolder(folderName, destinationFolderId, subFolderName) {

  try {
    // get destination Folder
    var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  }
  catch (e) {
    logEvent('Error getting destination folder: ' + e + e.stack);
    var destinationFolder = false;
  }


  // proceed if successfully got destination folder
  if (destinationFolder) {

    try {
      // create new Folder in destination
      var newFolder = destinationFolder.createFolder(folderName);

      // get new Drive Folder Url/Id
      var newFolderUrl = newFolder.getUrl();
      var newFolderId = newFolder.getId();

      // create sub-folder and get its Id
      var subFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId).createFolder(subFolderName).getId();

      // return Folder details for logging in Sheet and adding permissions
      var folderDetails = { newFolderUrl: newFolderUrl, newFolderId: newFolderId, subFolderID: subFolderID };
      return folderDetails;
    }
    catch (e) {
      logEvent('Error creating new Folders: ' + e + e.stack);
      return false;
    }
  }
  else {
    // return false as unable to get destination folder
    return false;
  }
}


/*
Function to add 'Edit' permission to each Folder from the provided
email address(es).
*/

function addPermissions(timeZone, dataSheet, permissionEmail, newFolderId, subFolderID, currentRow, permAddedCol) {

  // split up email address array to be able to loop through them separately
  var emailAddresses = permissionEmail.split(', ');
  Logger.log('emailAddresses array is: ' + emailAddresses);

  // get length of array for loop
  var emailAddressesLength = emailAddresses.length;


  try {
    // get Google Drive Folder
    var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId);
    var newSubFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(subFolderID);
  }
  catch (e) {
    logEvent('Error getting destination folder: ' + e + e.stack);
    var newFolder = false;
  }


  // proceed if successfully got destination folder
  if ((newFolder) && (newSubFolder)) {

    // loop through each email address and add as 'Editor' *******************
    for (var i = 0; i < emailAddressesLength; i++) {

      var emailAddress = emailAddresses[i];
      Logger.log('emailAddress for adding permission is: ' + emailAddress);

      try {
        // add 'Edit' permission using email address
        newFolder.addEditor(emailAddress);
        newSubFolder.addEditor(emailAddress);
        var addEditor = true;
      }
      catch (e) {
        logEvent('Error adding Editor: ' + e + e.stack);
        var addEditor = false;
      }

      if (addEditor) {
        // write timestamp into 'Permission Added?' cell
        var date = new Date;
        var timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, "dd/MM/yy @ HH:mm:ss");
        dataSheet.getRange(currentRow, permAddedCol).setValue(timeStamp);
      }
      else {
        // write error into 'Permission Added?' cell and return false value
        dataSheet.getRange(currentRow, permAddedCol).setValue('Error adding Editor. Please see Logs');
        return false;
      }

    }
    // loop through each email address and add as 'Editor' *******************

  }
  else {
    // write error into 'Permission Added?' cell and return false value
    dataSheet.getRange(currentRow, permAddedCol).setValue('Error getting folder. Please see Logs');
    // return false as unable to get Google Drive Folder
    return false;
  }


  // return true as all permissions added successfully
  return true;


}


/*
Function to output messages to the 'Log' sheet.
Can be called anywhere else in script.
*/

function logEvent(action) {
  
  // get the user running the script
  var theUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  
  // get the relevant spreadsheet to output log details
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log');
  
  // create and format a timestamp
  var dateTime = new Date();
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var niceDateTime = Utilities.formatDate(dateTime, timeZone, "dd/MM/yy @ HH:mm:ss");
  
  // create array of data for pasting into log sheet
  var logData = [niceDateTime, theUser, action];
  
  // append details into next row of log sheet
  logSheet.appendRow(logData);
  
}


/*
This Function creates a menu item to run this script.
*/

function onOpen() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Admin')
  .addItem('Create folders', 'getSpreadsheetData') // label for menu item, name of function to run.
  .addToUi();  
  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your sample Spreadsheet and your script, and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your question and the current issue of your script?

Comment: Hi, no worries about the English. At the moment I can add 1 subfolder to the main folder. I wold like to add in folder > subfolder & subfolder 2 & subfolder 3 etc. Hope that makes more sense. I have added anyother column to illustrate an extra folder

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the relationship between your sample Spreadsheet and your script, and your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thanks for helping. At the momen the sheet adds a folder on my google drive called "-"-"-folder". Inside folder it also creates a folder called "sub folder" I would like to run the script and be able to add a folder with more than one subfolders e.g. -folder 2" with sub folders 1,2 & 3

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Qsse3iR

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. From your additional information, in your sample Spreadsheet, you want to use only a sheet `Data` and you want to create a folder with the folder name of `folder` and a folder with the name of `sub folder` under `folder`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, what are "Subfolder 2 Name", "Email Address(es) for Permissions", "Folder Link" and "Permissions Added?"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239922/discussion-between-mee-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the line here that your script has.  What it does is it gets the folder id of the folder that was just created newFolderId. Then it creates a new folder under that with the name of subFolderName.

```
// create sub-folder and get its Id
var subFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId).createFolder(subFolderName).getId();
```

The easiest thing to do would be just to copy that line and create a second folder.

```
// create sub-folder and get its Id
var subFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId).createFolder(subFolderName2).getId();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

For creating multiple subfolders inside of one folder, you need to get the parent folder instance of [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder), and create the desired folders inside of it. In shorthand:

```
function createFolderAndSubfolders() {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.createFolder('Folder With Subfolders')
  var subFolderNames = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
  subFolderNames.forEach(subfolder => parentFolder.createFolder(subfolder))
}
```

There are several parts of the code you refer to that point to the creation of the subfolder.

```js
// Getting the name from a Sheets
var subFolderName = data[i][2];
// Creating the folder
var folderDetails = createFolder(folderName, destinationFolderId, subFolderName);
// Creating the Subfolder
var subFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId).createFolder(subFolderName).getId();
// Returning the info
var folderDetails = { newFolderUrl: newFolderUrl, newFolderId: newFolderId, subFolderID: subFolderID };
```

As [@DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70258317/14271633) says, a quick approach would be to call the function in charge of creating the subfolder twice. You could also create a small loop to add the desired subfolders.

I leave you how it would be using a small loop to create 3 subfolders.

```js
var subFoldersIDs = []
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var subFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId).createFolder(subFolderName + `-${i}`).getId()
  subFolderIDs.push(subFolderId)
}
var folderDetails = { newFolderUrl: newFolderUrl, newFolderId: newFolderId, subFolderIDs: subFolderIDs };
```

**Note 1** : Your code uses this information to perform other tasks, those parts of the code should also be accommodated for the correct functioning of the script.

**Note 2**: On the page you refer to, there is a [question](https://www.pbainbridge.co.uk/2021/05/bulk-create-google-drive-folders-with.html?showComment=1620123083163#c7489602630837117259) with the same content as yours.

###### Documentation

- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)
- [createFolder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFolder(String))

Comment: Thanks for the explantaion. Would the set up in the spreadsheet be okay like it is or would I need to do any adjustments there?

Comment: I tried to add the columns in the 2Create Folders.gs" but I get the error "ReferenceError: folderNameP3 is not defined"

Comment: I don't see `folderNameP3`, I do see `folderNameP2` or `folderNameP1` , in the code you refer. As I said in the answer, you should change more things in your code to make it work. Since you have copied it from another source, you should refer to it to complete the configuration as indicated.